# Why do numerals formatted by siunitx look different to those not formatted with siunitx?

Tags: tables, siunitx

Update: Apologies for my previous error

I am using `siunitx` to add a comma separator for thousands in tables. However, when I look at the tables, those not formatted with `\num{}` appear different. It looks like the same font and size, but the numbers formatted by `siunitx` seem to be a bit bolder/clearer. Do you agree?

Code and image below.

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{1.7cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]    
\centering
\begin{tabular}{TT}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Republic of Ireland}} \\
  \emph{\textbf{Total}} & \emph{\textbf{\%}} \\
  \hline  
  1333333 & \num{1333333} \\
  1000000 & \num{1000000} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example produces `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` and no output, please make an example without all the unrelated packages which just typesets  two numbers one with and one without siunitx, so they may be compared.

Comment: Your code doesn't run. `\begin{document}` is missing, as well as the definition of the `T` column.

Comment: Apologies, I have corrected now. I should have been more methodical in preparing things

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you try to reduce the example even more? Is the table necessary at all? I don't see how`xcolor`, `float`, `multirow` & Co should be relevant. Is the issue still there if you eliminate everything but `siunitx` and just do `1234546\num{123456}`?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it truly minimal, i.e., correspond exactly to the screenshot you posted. Feel free to revert. FWIW, I can detect no difference of the kind you say you're experiencing.

Comment: Can you comment on what looks different for you? The screenshots are rather small. With `siunitx`, there could be a font issue which also relates to text or math mode (which are settings in `siunitx`). Your screenshot also looks like one version is rasterized but again, it's not really clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I cannot detect any difference in the appearance of numbers formatted by hand or with the help of `\num`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4}
\usepackage{icomma} % no special treatment of commas in math mode

\begin{document}

1,333,333 1,234,567         % manual formatting, text mode

$1,333,333$ $1,234,567$     % manual formatting, math mode

\num{1333333} \num{1234567} % formatting with '\num'

\end{document}
```